# TypeError - "callback is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote some code based off someone elses code. Their code worked perfectly (see it [here](https://github.com/mxsscott/scratchext/blob/master/exts/weather.js)), but mine gives me `Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function`

A snippet of my code:

```
ext.verify_acc = function(username, password, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '//api.bos2.cf/?type=verify&username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&callback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (responseText) {
            messages = responseText['success'];
            callback(messages);
        }
    })
};
```

Also, All the code has to stay in the `ext.verify_acc` function. What I want this code to do will not work if any code is not inside it.

And just encase, the script that calls the function:

```
var descriptor = {
    blocks: [
        ['b', 'Check credentials %s %s', 'verify_acc', 'Username', 'Password'],
    ]//                                        ^
};//                                           ^
//--------THE-FUNCTION-THAT-GETS-CALLED--------^-------------------------------
```

The up above script renders a block that when clicked calls the function

If you know why it is saying `callback is not a function` then please tell me.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? You need to pass a callback.

Comment: @SLaks I think I did everything right, but it gives me the error. I want to know what I did wrong. Doesn't it pass a callback?

Comment: @csf30816 without seeing the code that takes the block from your second snippet and calls the function in your first snippet, there is no way we can know.

Comment: Your function takes a callback.  You need to pass one.

Comment: @SLaks I put ```&callback=?``` at the end of the request, doesn't that pass a callback?

Comment: You need to _call your function_ and pass the parameters it expects.

Comment: How does the `descriptor` object or the `blocks` array get used?  What arguments are being passed to verify_acc() ?  Below:

`ext.verify_acc = function(username, password, callback) {`

and above:

`$.ajax({`

can you do:

`console.log(arguments)`

and post what that says?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the function, not the function name:

```
var descriptor = {
    blocks: [
        ['b', 'Check credentials %s %s', ext.verify_acc, 'Username', 'Password'],
    ]
};
```

But I don't think you're getting anywhere, if I read the source code you've mentioned. Or they may use evil `eval()`.

Comment: I am building an extension for something, so all I need to do is ```'verify_acc'```. If I try to do ```ext.verify_acc```it would not work :(

Comment: Then just use `verify_acc` and not `'verify_acc'`.